# How to move my cursor position in one line edit to another line edit using pyqt4

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4

Here is my sample code.When i click the ok button i need to change my cursor position to another line edit.How can i change my cursor position in the sample code.Can any one please help me.
Given below is my code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui


class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):
        self.vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.le1 = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        self.le2 = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        self.le3 = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        self.ok = QtGui.QPushButton("OK")
        self.ok.clicked.connect(self.moving_position)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.le1)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.le2)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.le3)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.ok)
        self.setLayout(self.vbox)

        self.show()
    def moving_position(self):
        pass
        #how to move cursor to next line edit


def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try: `self.le1.setFocus()`